# PHP and JavaScript: Getting a HTML value in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a span, it looks like this:

```
<span class="price" id="product-price-167">€47.00</span>
```

The 47.00 is set dynamically using JavaScript. Now when the user clicks a button, a request to a PHP script is being triggered. I need the 47.00 in that script. How could I do that? I know JS is front end and PHP is server side, but is there some way?

Thanks :)

**Solution:** I am using a hidden field and read that using

```
$price = $_POST["price"];
```

Comment: A hidden field in form? If "when the user clicks a button, a request to a PHP script is being triggered"...

Comment: We need to know more about your markup - how is the request being made right now, a plain form? Or you can just do it from scratch yet?

Comment: Would it not be easier to have the JS that sets this text to also place that value into a hidden element in the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to retrieve the value of the element:

```
var value = $('#product-price-167').text();
```

I think that should give you the 47.00.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = 'path-to-script.php';
var data = 'price='+Number($('#product-price-167').replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")); // to remove redundant [currency] characters
$.post(path, data, function(returnText){
    // do stuff here
});
```

That should do.

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing by float. It's not reliable for money. Use var parsedPrice = Number(data.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

Comment: Ok… why is it not reliable for money?

Comment: Same reason it's bad to use float columns to store money in a DB. You'll never be sure of what you're actually getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

You can get the price inside the span:

```
var price = $('#product-price-167').text();
```

You can then parse price accordingly to get rid of the Euro sign. Without knowing exactly where your button will be placed or how it will work, it's kind of difficult to tell you how to get it to your PHP script.

Note that you shouldn't parse as Float if this is a serious application: Use

```
var parsedNumber = Number(price.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use jquery to post that value to php page using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// i m assuming that 167 in id product-price-167 comes from database in a loop

function buttonClick(pid){
 var price=$("#product-price-"+pid).text();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data  : "price="+price,
        url   : "yourphppage.php",
        success :function(data){
            //return something from php page
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

and your input button

```
<input type="button" onclick="buttonClick('167')" />
```